# Azure SAML 2.0 Error only on night-time

Tags: azure, saml

I get this error:

```
AADSTS75005 the request is not a valid saml2 protocol message
```

from around 23:00 - to 08:00 in the morning, it varies some in time. It works great on the day, but nights and early mornings i get the error.

This is the authRequest i send with redirect:

`<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_79a4e166-3b3b-496c-bc8a-4f887f854390" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" IssueInstant="2014-11-27T10:38:52Z"><Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://response.url.com</Issuer></samlp:AuthnRequest>`

From what i have read from azure the issueInstant i send with the authRequest doesnt matter, even though I have tried changeing it without result.

What can I try to continue troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the tomcat server time that was the difference. If i use 
-Duser.timezone=UTC
in the tomcat startup it works :)